# Graphical issue with UISearchBar on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have graphical issues using the UISearchBar.How can I fix it ?
[image]

here's my code:

```
    [self.view addSubview:self.resultObject.searchBar];
```

I have add

```
self.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1);
[self.searchBar sizeToFit];
```

to viewDidLoad but I still have the same problem.

Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place your search bar at `(0, viewController.topLayoutGuide.length)`; you are adding it at `(0,0)`. In iOS7, views are by default under the status bar.

Comment: You should use the [`topLayoutGuide`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/topLayoutGuide) property of `UIViewController` instead of hardcoding 20 pts for the status bar height.